# Task Manager has been disabled

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

In the past I had an issue where my admin had disabled Task Manager, I can't remeber exactly how I fixed it, but it was a part of windows where you can add which application would not be able to run.. like going into a sandbox or just a dummy run

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: If your admin has decided to disable it, then it is best to ask them to enable it for you.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555480

Comment: you can get fired for circumventing company policies. i know a person who got fired for these.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day we worked around this by modifying the task manager executable, as that is how the policy is enforced, by the program itself. That way we could leave the registry and group policy unmodified, and just keep a modified copy of the program on disk somewhere.

Changing "DisableTaskMgr" to "DisablePaskMgr" meant it no longer could read the policy key, and ran just fine. This still works on all versions up to Windows 7 (I just tested it, file offset 38590B).

Alternatively you can change the registry key itself to 0, or use an alternative task manager, such as [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Comment: I alrady changed the "DisableTaskMgr" in the registry, I enabled in the Group Policy and nothing... the option is no longer greyed out but nothing opens

Also Process Explorer doesn't run as well, I remember ths being added to a certain place that prevent them from running.. but I don't remember where is that

Comment: @Emmanuel interesting, I can still run process explorer even when I disable task manager by either registry or group policy. Is it possible there is another system program or policy that is either blacklisting or whitelisting applications?